# Jboss trying to load dependent class from other war file

Tags: jboss, dependencies, jboss7.x, jboss-modules

I don't know how but jboss is trying to load dependencies from other deployed war file which ends with a linkage error. And so my soap web service fails.

To give an example;
I have a war file A.war deployed and working so far. I then write another web app with web services in it and deployed it. When I try to call my second app (B.war) it is trying to go to A.war to define the module

Please see below exception. this has taken my 2 days and now I am driving crazy moment by moment.

Jboss version is : 7.1.3

```
20:11:00,101 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (http-/192.168.180.144:8080-1) Failed to define class com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.SOAPDocumentImpl in Module "deployment.msdp-advanced-subscription-api-JAXWS.war:main" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link com/sun/xml/messaging/saaj/soap/SOAPDocumentImpl (Module "deployment.msdp-advanced-subscription-api-JAXWS.war:main" from Service Module Loader)

20:11:00,113 ERROR [org.jboss.ws.common.invocation.InvocationHandlerJAXWS] (http-/192.168.180.144:8080-1) Method invocation failed with exception: null: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at org.jboss.ws.common.invocation.AbstractInvocationHandlerJSE.invoke(AbstractInvocationHandlerJSE.java:111)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.JBossWSInvoker._invokeInternal(JBossWSInvoker.java:182)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.JBossWSInvoker.invoke(JBossWSInvoker.java:127)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:58)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.SynchronousExecutor.execute(SynchronousExecutor.java:37)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:107)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:207)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.RequestHandlerImpl.handleHttpRequest(RequestHandlerImpl.java:91)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.transport.ServletHelper.callRequestHandler(ServletHelper.java:169)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.CXFServletExt.invoke(CXFServletExt.java:87)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:185)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:108)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar:1.0.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.CXFServletExt.service(CXFServletExt.java:135)
    at org.jboss.wsf.spi.deployment.WSFServlet.service(WSFServlet.java:140) [jbossws-spi-2.0.4.GA.jar:2.0.4.GA]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar:1.0.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:165) [jboss-as-web-7.1.3.Final.jar:7.1.3.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:372) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:679) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:931) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/xml/messaging/saaj/soap/SOAPDocumentImpl
    at com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.SOAPPartImpl.<init>(SOAPPartImpl.java:106) [saaj-impl-1.3.16-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPPart1_1Impl.<init>(SOAPPart1_1Impl.java:70) [saaj-impl-1.3.16-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.Message1_1Impl.getSOAPPart(Message1_1Impl.java:90) [saaj-impl-1.3.16-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.saaj.SAAJOutInterceptor.handleMessage(SAAJOutInterceptor.java:125)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.handler.soap.SOAPHandlerInterceptor.handleMessage(SOAPHandlerInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.handler.soap.SOAPHandlerInterceptor.handleMessage(SOAPHandlerInterceptor.java:70)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:531)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:461)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:364)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:317)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:88)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:134)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy107.getService(Unknown Source)
    at com.ericsson.jawwal.msdp.ca.utils.LocalMCIUtils.getServiceSubDistributionList(LocalMCIUtils.java:92) [classes:]
    at com.ericsson.jawwal.msdp.ca.LocalMCIService.getDistributionList(LocalMCIService.java:100) [classes:]
    ... 38 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.SOAPDocumentImpl from [Module "deployment.msdp-advanced-subscription-api-JAXWS.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
    ... 54 more
```

Interstingly this is the first time after I startup my jboss. If I try to rerun this same test this time the last ClassNotFoundException not shown.

Answer (score 2):

Restart JBoss

Seriously. I ran into this exact same issue. It was happening in just one of our environments. It came out of nowhere. I decided to restart the JBoss instance before getting too deep into the issue - problem solved.

Comment: you have no idea how much I worked on this issue and jboss restarts. I have re-wrote the application in a modern way, simplified the dependency tree. and issue gone.

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same problem and the resolution was quite painful.

I had an instance of `Wildfly` with several web-services already deployed. I added my service, and it failed on every call.

The issue was in the old third-party library that was used in my service. It caused `JAR` hell, so our partners had to rewrite it.

`Wildfly` has its own implementation of `SAAJ` library in modules/ folder and tries to load it automatically, so you'll have to check all your dependencies and exclude `saaj-impl.jar`.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I did the same and re-implemented the service. thankfully it was a small one.